# How to access an instance variable inside JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have the following controller actions:

```
def new
   @tag = Tag.new({company_id: current_member.company_id })
  end

 def create
    @tag = Tag.new(tag_params)
    @companyid = current_member.company_id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @tag.save
          format.html {redirect_to root_path}
          format.json {render :json=> @tag}
      else
        format.html {redirect_to root_path}
      end
    end
  end
```

Inside my new.html.slim view file I have:

```
= simple_form_for @tag, url: tags_new_path, html: {id:'tag_form_submit', method: :post}, format: :js, remote:true do |t|
  =t.input :name, placeholder: 'tag'
  =t.button :submit, "submit tag", id:"submit_tag_button"

javascript:
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit_tag_button").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      <!-- $("#tag_form_submit").hide(); -->
      <!-- $('#add_tag_tag').hide(); -->
      var text = $("#inputbox").val();
      var name = $("#tag_name").val();
      var datatosend = { tag: {name:name, company_id: "#{@companyid}" } };
      $.ajax({
        url: "/tags/new",
        dataType: "json",
        method: "post",
        data: datatosend,
        success: function(result){
          console.log(result)
          var nameVar=result.name;
          var idVar=result.id;
          console.log(nameVar);
          console.log(idVar);
          var newspan='<span class="checkbox"><label for="job_tag_ids_'+idVar+'" name="job[tag_ids]"><input class="check_boxes optional form-control" data-remote="true" id="job_tag_ids_'+idVar+'" name="job[tag_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="'+idVar+'">' + nameVar + '</label></span>';
          $("#all_tags > div.form-group.check_boxes.optional.job_tags > div").append(newspan);
          <!-- $(#event_tag_ids).append('hi'); -->
          if ($("#event_tag_ids").length){
              $("#event_tag_ids").append('<option value="'+idVar+'">'+nameVar+'</option>');
          }

          // after its appended, erase from form input
           console.log(result.company_id);
          $("#tag_name").val("");
        }
      })
    })
  });
```

In my `datatosend` varible I am trying to send:

```
   var datatosend = { tag: {name:name, company_id: "#{@companyid}" } };
```

but `@companyid` is being posted as null. Why?

How do I successfully access `@companyid` from the controller inside my JavaScript so I can send it in when making my AJAX post call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only assigning the `@companyid` instance variable in the `create` action of your controller, not the `new` action.

The view template you posted is rendered as part of the `new` action. So you should change your controller:

```
def new
  @companyid = current_member.company_id
  @tag = Tag.new(company_id: @companyid)
end
```

Comment: that was it!! such a silly mistake - sometimes its helpful to use a pair of second eyes , id been struggling with this issue for a long time! thanks again!

Comment: ...or since the company_id is an attribute of the tag, `@tag.company_id`